# matplotlib legend avoids points when manually setting coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code, I generate a scatterplot where the legend is manually placed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

frame = frame = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4], "y": [4, 3, 2, 1]})
ax = frame.plot.scatter(x="x", y="y", label="dots")
plt.savefig("dots.pdf")
for y in [0.6, 0.7, 0.8]:
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, y), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.savefig("dots_{}.png".format(y))
```

It looks like the legend does not obey  the placement instructions when it would make it hide a point:

[image: y=0.6]
[image: y=0.7]
[image: y=0.8]

Is there a way to avoid this? I mean, how to really force the placement of the legend?

Comment: What do you want to avoid exactly? You want to avoid the legend avoiding something?

Comment: Yes, I want to force the placement. I tried to make this clearer in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in reading [my answer to "How to put the legend out of the plot"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317). While it handles the case of putting the legend outside of the plot, most of it is applicable to placing the legend just anywhere, including inside the plot.

Most imporantly, the legend position is determined by the `loc` parameter. If you do not specify this parameter in the call to `legend()`, matplotlib will try to place the legend whereever it thinks it's best, (default is `loc ="best"`).

In case you want to place the legend at a certain position, you may specify the coordinates of its lower left corner to `loc`:

```
ax.legend(loc=(0.5, 0.6))
```

If you want to specify another corner of the legend to be at a certain position, you need to specify the corner with the `loc` argument and the position using `bbox_to_anchor`:

```
ax.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.6))
```

Comment: It works well, but I don't understand how this interacts with 'plt.tight_layout()': If I put the legend at the top (`ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, loc="lower left")`), the legend is partially eaten out. I thought `plt.tight_layout()` was meant to make everything fit in the image, and I observe the contrary.

Comment: No, `tight_layout` will not take the legend into account. But the case you descibe is sufficiently covered in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317) I linked to.